# Get all rows where column A hours difference is not 8 to 9 hours different from column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I have two datetime fields. I want to select the fields based on condition in which the 1st datetime column is NOT 8 or 9 hours ahead of the 2nd datetime column.

Any idea how I can solve that?

Something like:

```
WHERE ((DATEPART(HOUR, tableA.date1) != (DATEPART(HOUR, tableA.date2))
```

I'm not sure if the DATEPART(HOUR,...)) thing will work if we have dates from two dates, for example 1st Jan 11:20PM and 2nd Jan 09:50 AM.

Comment: Try DATEDIFF(...) NOT IN (8,9)

Comment: Be careful using datediff here. Datediff counts the number of thresholds crossed, it does not count the number of hours elapsed between 2 time periods. Consider 8:59am to 4:01pm. That is clearly 7 hours but datediff will say it is 8. select DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2015-01-01 08:59', '2015-01-01 16:01')

Comment: @SeanLange which approach do you recommend? Thanks

Comment: That depends on what you are really trying to do. If you want it to be accurate to 8 hours I would do something like Date1 < DATEADD(HOUR, 8, Date2) OR Date1 > DATEADD(HOUR, 9, Date2). This approach ensures you have a 1 hour window that is exactly 8 hours after date1.

Answer (score 0):

The `DATEDIFF` using `MINUTE` and dividing by `60` will bring you exact difference even if the time in `DATETIMECOL1` and `DATETIMECOL2` is `8:59am to 4:01pm`.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DATETIMECOL2,DATETIMECOL1)/60) < 8 
OR (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DATETIMECOL2,DATETIMECOL1)/60) > 9
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c3f3/4)**

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN`. The query below may help -

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table a
LEFT JOIN your_table b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.date1, b.date2) < 480) OR (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.date1, b.date2) < 540)
```